# Is there a way to make certain functions "private" in a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

When my shell starts, I load an external script that has a few functions I use to test things.  Something like:

```
# Include Service Test Tools
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
. $scriptPath\SvcTest.ps1
```

In `SvcTest.ps1`, I have two functions:

```
function isURI ([string] $address)
{
   ($address -as [System.URI]).AbsoluteURI -ne $null
}
```

As well as:

```
function Test-Service ([string] $url)
{
   if (-Not (isURI($url)))
   {
      Write-Host "Invalid URL: $url"
      return
   }

   # Blah blah blah, implementation not important
}
```

The `isURI` function is basically just a utility function that allows `Test-Service` and perhaps other functions validate URIs.  However, when I start my shell, I see that `isURI` is a function loaded globally.  I can even type `isURI http://www.google.com` from the command line and get back `True`.

**My Question:** Is there a way to make `isURI` *private*, so that only functions within `SvcTest.ps1` can use it, while still allowing `Test-Service` to be global?  Basically, I'm looking for a way to use property encapsulation within PowerShell scripts.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for a module?

Comment: Hmm, maybe?  I'm reading [about_scopes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx) right now and it's a bit of help.  I thought I could name my function `script:isURI` and it would change the scope.  However, I can still reference `isURI` from the command line.

Comment: If a function isn't exported from the module, it won't be visible in a child scope. See `help about_Modules` for more details.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - Yea looks like modules are the only way to do this.  Everything in a script has to be at the same scope, otherwise functions can't depend on other functions.  I'll go learn up on modules.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - Just got it working as a module, and it does exactly what I want (though you have to create a manifest and specify which functions to export).  Can you add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Just FYI, a manifest isn't required. Added answer as requested.

Comment: Thanks.  If you don't create a manifest, it works just like a `.ps1` file; all functions get added to the current scope.

Comment: Not if you use `export-modulemember` in your module to specify only which functions get exported.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're asking for functionality that's available by creating a module.

Modules let you encapsulate code and export only desired aliases and/or functions. A module manifest is not strictly required; if you don't use a manifest, you can use `Export-ModuleMember` to specify what members you want exported from the module.

See the `help about_Modules` about topic for more information.

Comment: and this shows how you can not only 'privatize' but duplicate names performing in different modules, should you need to do so.... https://evotec.xyz/executing-hidden-or-private-functions-from-powershell-modules/

Answer (score 24):

In fact, if you call a .ps1 file, *by default* any functions and variables declared within it are scoped privately within the script (this is referred to as "script scope"). Since you're seeing both functions defined globally, I infer that you're *dot-sourcing* **SvcTest.ps1**, i.e. invoking it like this

```
PS> . <path>\SvcTest.ps1
```

rather than *calling* it like this

```
PS> <path>\SvcTest.ps1
```

You have two options.

**1.** If your private function is only used by one other function in the script, you can declare the private function within the body of the function that uses it, and invoke the script by dot-sourcing it:

```powershell
function Test-Service ([string] $url)
{
    function isURI ([string] $address)
    {
        ($address -as [System.URI]).AbsoluteURI -ne $null
    }

    if (-Not (isURI($url)))
    {
        Write-Host "Invalid URL: $url"
        return
    }

    # Blah blah blah, implementation not important
}
```

**2.** (ed. This option does not work powershell 7.3.4, it should either be removed or fixed, see comment) - If the private function is needed by more than one other function within the script (or even if not, this is an alternative to the above), explicitly declare global scope for any functions that you want defined globally, and then call the script rather than dot-sourcing it:

```powershell
function isURI ([string] $address)
{
   ($address -as [System.URI]).AbsoluteURI -ne $null
}


function global:Test-Service ([string] $url)
{
   if (-Not (isURI($url)))
   {
      Write-Host "Invalid URL: $url"
      return
   }

   # Blah blah blah, implementation not important
}
```

In either case, **Test-Service** will be defined in the global scope, and **isURI** will be restricted to the script scope.

---

* One thing that might confuse the issue here is that PowerShell only looks for executables in the path, not the current working directory, unless `.` has been added to the path (which is not the case by default). So, it's typical in PowerShell when invoking scripts in the working directory to precede the script name with `.\`. Don't confuse the `.` representing the working directory with the dot-sourcing operator. This calls a script:

```powershell
PS> .\SvcTest.ps1
```

This dot-sources it:

```powershell
PS> . .\SvcTest.ps1
```

Comment: 2nd option does not work! Without dot-sourcing the internal function just fails to run. Tested on powershell v5 and v7: 
`PS> .\SvcTest.ps1`
`PS> Test-Service "http://web.com"`
`isURI : The term 'isURI' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use a private scope for your function, it is done like this in Powershell.

```
function Private:isURI ([string] $address)
{
   ($address -as [System.URI]).AbsoluteURI -ne $null
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  I can still run `isURI` from the command line.  I think because `. TestSvc.ps1` adds everything to the current scope?

Comment: Use & instead of . to avoid adding the functions to the global context.

Comment: @EBGreen - I tried that (and then making `Test-Service` global).  Then running `Test-Service` gives the error *The term 'isURI' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet*

Comment: couldn't you encapsulate that one-line verification inside your Test-Service function avoiding the need for the second private isURI function.

Comment: @Knuckle-Dragger - In this case, sure.  I'm worried about other utility functions that are far more complex and used across many other functions.

Comment: @Cole9350 - I want any functions within SvcTest.ps1 to be able to use `isURI` but nothing else.  And I want *certain* functions within `SvcTest.ps1` to be global.  Think of `SvcTest.ps1` as a class; I want certain functions to be private and some to be public.

Comment: @Mike The closest you'll get to that is modules

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried moving the isURI function to be a script, and then dot sourcing in your other functions instead of running it as a function?

isuri.ps1:

```
Param([string] $address)
($address -as [System.URI]).AbsoluteURI -ne $null
```

svctext.ps1:

```
function Test-Service ([string] $url)
{
   if (-Not (. .\isURI($url)))
   {
      Write-Host "Invalid URL: $url"
      return
   }

   # Blah blah blah, implementation not important
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when creating a .psm1 module. If you use Export-ModuleMember (as Bill_Stewart suggests which is the accepted answer) for the "public" function you can expose your selected function(s). All other functions not exported are hidden publicly but can still be used by the module.

If you don't include the Export-Module statement in your module, all members are automatically exposed.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/export-modulemember?view=powershell-7.2[Export-ModuleMember][1]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/export-modulemember?view=powershell-7.2%5BExport-ModuleMember%5D%5B1%5D)

```
function isURI ([string] $address)
{
   ($address -as [System.URI]).AbsoluteURI -ne $null
}

function Test-Service ([string] $url)
{
   if (-Not (isURI($url)))
   {
      Write-Host "Invalid URL: $url"
      return
   }

   # Blah blah blah, implementation not important
}

# only expose Test-Service publicly
Export-ModuleMember -Function Test-Service
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something I could use in my Powershell profile. My workaround is to remove the function when it's not needed anymore:

```
Remove-Item Function:\FunctionName
```